# WCF One-Way Operation exception handling

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using a one-way WCF service contract to push data from a server to a set of registered clients. The application mostly works fine, however users report occasional disconnects in the production environment.

When I try to reproduce the error in development, eg. by killing the server, I see the cause of the exception is available in the $exception debugger variable (as shown below). I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268947/exception-is-defined-in-locals) that it's not possible to retrieve the value of this error in code, but is it possible to catch and log this error using some technique or configuration?

I imagine it would be quite straightforward in a two way RPC type call, but with the one way contract it's not as clear from the documentation. I would *love* to be able to be able to run the WCF network trace tool, but because the disconnects are so intermittent, and the production environment rather serious it's not something I can do very easily.

[image]

Here is a snippet of the service contract:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void SendGridState(GridState grid);
```

The service binding:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding
{
    MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
    MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
    ReliableSession = { InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue }
};
```

The faulted event handler:

```
clientChannel.Faulted += delegate
{
    connectionStatus = CommunicationState.Faulted;
}
```